# How to stop a Xamarin Forms behavior used to asynchronously translate an image?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

In a Xamarin.Forms project, I'm trying to repeatedly translate an image from a position A(x,y) to a position B(x,y) and back, from B to A. To achieve this, I read that is possible to customize behaviors.

I extend Behavior class, overriding OnAttachedTo and OnDetachingFrom. And in the OnAttachedTo method I start a Task which repeatedly does the two translations.

This is my Behavior class:

```
public class MoveImageBehavior : Behavior<Image>
{
    private Image _Image = null;

    public static readonly BindableProperty AnimatedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Animated", typeof(bool), typeof(ImageAnimatedBehavior), defaultValue: false);
    public bool Animated
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AnimatedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimatedProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Image image)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(image);

        _Image = image;
        Animated = true;
        Task.Run(AnimateImage);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Image image)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(image);
        _Image = null;
    }

    private async void AnimateImage()
    {
        while (_Image != null && Animated)
        {
            await _Image.TranslateTo(100, 100, 1000);
            await _Image.TranslateTo(0, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The image in the xaml file:

```
<ContentView>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image_translating" Source="my_icon" Aspect="AspectFit">
            <Image.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:MoveImageBehavior Animated="{Binding ImageTranslating}" BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference image_translating}}"/>
            </Image.Behaviors>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

The Image repeatedly translates correctly as I want, but I'm not able to stop the while routine. The property binding doesn't work when Animated is set to false in the ViewModel and OnDetachingFrom is never called.
What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the document, we can see that:

> The **OnDetachingFrom** method is fired when the behavior is removed from
>   the control. This method receives a reference to the control to which
>   it is attached, and is used to perform any required cleanup. For
>   example, you could unsubscribe from an event on a control to prevent
>   memory leaks.

It will only fired when you remove the behavior from the image. I would give you an example about how to stop the animation:

I defined an bool property in the code behind to control stop or not stop:

```
  public bool showA  = true;
```

And I add a button as an example to stop the animation:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showA = !showA;

    if (showA)
    {
        image_translating.Behaviors.Add(new MoveImageBehavior());

    }
    else
    {
        var toRemove = image_translating.Behaviors.FirstOrDefault(b => b is MoveImageBehavior);
        if (toRemove != null)
        {
            image_translating.Behaviors.Remove(toRemove);
        }
    }
}
```

Also in your `OnDetachingFrom` method, do not set the image to null, it will cause a null expection, just set the Animated to false :

```
protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Image image)
{
    base.OnDetachingFrom(image);
    Animated = false;
}
```

You can convert my click event to some binding in your project and make it work.

Refer: [creating-a-xamarinforms-behaviorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating#creating-a-xamarinforms-behavior)